# tree command does not show hierarchical structure?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, open-source, utilities

The following resources show `tree` should output hierarchical directory structure [view directory structure](https://ostechnix.com/view-directory-tree-structure-linux/)

[image]

So I did `brew install tree`. But the `tree` command does not print hierarchical output:

```
(py367) 11:31:12/hercules-api $tree -d src
[        160 Jan 20 17:28]  src
[        224 Feb 13 13:52]  src/alembic_migrations
[        160 Feb 13 23:21]  src/alembic_migrations/__pycache__
[        256 Feb 13 13:52]  src/alembic_migrations/versions
[        544 Feb 13 23:35]  src/alembic_migrations/versions/__pycache__
```

Is there a switch on `tree` to get the expected or a different code base/compile/install which has this feature on macOS?

Comment: Check if you have more than one tree command installed and the non-brew one is getting called.  `which -a tree` should list them all (if there is more than one).

Comment: @DCSlagel Before installing `tree` from brew there was none available.  in any case `$which tree    /opt/brew/bin/tree`

Comment: Okay it sounds like there is only one 'tree' there.  Side-note... The '-a' tells 'which' to list all the executables for 'tree'.  So if there was more than one, '-a' would display all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `tree`.  But I have found:

`brew info tree` which tells me the tree website is:

[The Tree Command for Linux Home Page](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/), which links to:

[Man page for Tree](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/tree.1.html), which tells me:

The `-d` is used to list directories only, which is what you have done. Without the `-d` all files are shown.

To confirm this I have installed `tree` and the `-d` works for me, for example:

```
gilby@Beth/Users/gilby/Projects% tree -d cacti
cacti
├── 947301-387ecde4b13cf7e8daf05ab154461505b5cd027d
├── RRD-to-CSV-master
├── TechnicolorStatScraper-master
│   ├── Cacti
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   └── __pycache__
├── cacti-0.8.8b
│   ├── cli
│   ├── docs
│   │   ├── html
│   │   │   └── images
│   │   ├── pdf
│   │   └── txt
│
```

Comment: I do want only directories and as you see it is not hierarchical. Removing `-d` adds a bunch of files into the still non-hierarchical output

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Sorry, did not appreciate you only wanted dirs.  Was making it like the sample in your question.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects I have installed tree (via home-brew) and `tree -d` does give me the hierarchical output with just directories (and packages).

Comment: huh, then i wonder why there  is the difference between the behaviors

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is `tree`, try:

```
$ alias tree=$'find . -print | sed -e \'s;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g\''
```

And then just run `tree`.